# What is error? i'm trying to fill table with random values

Tags: mysql, random, insert

I have two similar tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `t1` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`c1` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`c2` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `idx_c1` (`c1`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `t2` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`c1` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`c2` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `idx_c1` (`c1`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

I want to fill both tables with random values:

```
drop procedure if exists random_records;
truncate table t1;
truncate table t2;
delimiter $$

create procedure random_records(n int)
begin
set @i=1;
set @m=100000;
while @i <= n do
    insert into t1(c1,c2) values(rand()*@m,rand()*@m);
    insert into t2(c1,c2) values(rand()*@m,rand()*@m);
   set @i=@i+1;
end while;
end $$

delimiter ;

call random_records(100);
select * from t1 limit 10;
select * from t2 limit 10;
select count(*) from t1;
select count(*) from t2;
```

Here is what i see in table t1:
[image: Below is what i see in table t1:]

I don't understand why there is a lot of '0' and'1'
Function count() returns 210 for t1 and 208 for t2 - one mystery more

Comment: If you get 208 or 210 rows for a call of random_records(100), this is not the code you showed here (as it should only produce 100 rows), or you are doing other things with it than you say here. Please make sure you are testing and posting the actual code. A first step could be to test your code e.g. on [https://dbfiddle.uk/](https://dbfiddle.uk/) or similar, so get an isolated test environment.

Comment: 1) Solalarflare wrote: "this is not the code you showed here ". -- I showed all text i have. Not a single letter more. I ran this script with phpMyAdmin and HeidiSQL. Everywhere 0 and 1.
maybe somebody will execute this script. You just need to copy and paste the script I provided.

Comment: Running the code once cannot produce 208 rows per table. So you are doing something differently than you show here. Maybe you do not truncate the tables (as in your post) and the 0 are some artifact from a previous run with some different procedure, and limit 10 always shows those old rows. E.g. phpmyadmin doesn't support "delimiter" as code, so maybe it didn't do what you think it did. But the code as it is written in your question (and executed as written in your question) will not be able to add 208 rows, nor 210, so you might be looking at the wrong place, so I would first check for that.

Comment: And to give you a starting point, I made a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ncRyLQY3) for you, it does as expected with the code you posted. Basically, you now have to figure out where your situation differs from that. It's hard for us to guess what it could be (although blaming phpmyadmin is sometimes a good guess).

Comment: i ran your fiddle. All select are empty and both count()=0

Comment: Sorry, if the fiddle fails for you (it doesn't for me, and it should at least show you the result of the last run before you run it yourself), then I am out of options. The only thing I could imagine is some language setting in your browser that both fiddle and phpmyadmin relay to mysql which might cause problems for some reason, but I would expect an error message in that case. Nevertheless, I still assume that the main problem is not the code itself.

Comment: thank you for your willingness to help. I'll try another browser tomorrow

Comment: It seems that it wil not help, because HeidiSQL (desktop program) also shows wrong results. Maybe the reason is the version of mariadb used. But fiddle do not use mysql installed on my computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely reason for the presence of many zeros and ones in the `c1` and `c2` columns of both tables is that the `rand()` function is returning very small numbers. This is because the `@m` variable, which is used to scale the random numbers generated by `rand()`, is set to a relatively low value of 100,000.

As a result, the random numbers generated are mostly between 0 and 0.00001, which is why you are seeing many zeros and ones in the tables. **To fix this, you can increase the value of `@m` to a higher number, such as 1,000,000 or even 10,000,000, to generate larger random numbers.**

As for the discrepancy in the number of rows in the two tables, it is likely due to the fact that the `insert` statements in the `random_records` procedure are not being executed atomically.

This means that there is a chance that one of the `insert` statements could fail, resulting in fewer rows being inserted into one of the tables. To fix this, you can wrap the insert statements in a transaction to ensure that they are executed as a single unit of work.

For example, you can modify the `random_records` procedure as follows:

```
drop procedure if exists random_records;
truncate table t1;
truncate table t2;
delimiter $$

create procedure random_records(n int)
begin
set @i=1;
set @m=1000000;

start transaction;

while @i <= n do
    insert into t1(c1,c2) values(rand()*@m,rand()*@m);
    insert into t2(c1,c2) values(rand()*@m,rand()*@m);
   set @i=@i+1;
end while;

commit;
end $$

delimiter ;
```

This should ensure that the `insert` statements are executed atomically and that the number of rows in both tables is consistent.

Comment: Nothing of suggested helped. Still I only get zeros and ones  in three or four records even if multiplier=1e8. It is impossible. RAND function must return pseudo random value with uniform distribution. So chance to receive several records of ten with 0 an 1 is unprobable.

Comment: I replaced rand with my own
`
SET @x=2371;
CREATE FUNCTION my_rand()
RETURNS FLOAT
BEGIN
SET @X=(17853*@X+29871) % 1000;
RETURN @X;
END $$
`
everything is the same